# what does $* mean in shell

Tags: shell, shell-script

What does `$*` mean in shell?

I have code two function, `run_command` and `run_test`, they are called like this:

```
if [ -n "`echo ${GOAT_COMMANDS} | grep $1`" ]; then
  run_command $*
else
  run_test $*
fi
```

I want to understand what `$*` means, but Google search is very bad for searching these kinds of things.

Comment: You may want to use [duckduckgo.com](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+does+%24*+mean+in+shell&atb=v92-6__&ia=qa) to search for special characters

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$*` is [all the parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) to the script or function, split into separate arguments on whitespace.

If you have a function:

```
foo() {
    for x in $*
    do
        echo $x
    done
}
```

then running `foo 1 "2 3 4" 5` will output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

That is, the quoted string `"2 3 4"` will be split into three separate "words".

When you **don't** want to split the arguments into separate words like that, you can use `$@`. If the same function used `"$@"` in place of `$*`, it would output:

```
1
2 3 4
5
```

That is, the quoted string would not be split into separate words. This is like listing all the positional parameters out explicitly: `"$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" ...`. In general, this is probably the one you want to use - the word-splitting will often lead to nasty bugs that are hard to track down.

At the top level of a script (not inside a function), these refer to the arguments given to the script itself.

Your example is calling either `run_command` or `run_test` with all of the arguments to this script or function, split into separate words. If the script were run as `script.sh "hello world" 2 3` then it would have the effect of running:

```
run_command hello world 2 3
```

Comment: Some related [related reading material](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) for the OP.

Comment: Does `$*` remove the `"`? I.e. does the first version output `1,2,3,4,5`, and not `1,"2,3,4",5`?

Comment: @Svish: Quotes `"2 3 4"` are [removed by the shell right at the start](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes) - they make the whole thing a single "word", rather than splitting it into three the way it usually would.

Answer (score 3):

`$*` means pass all parameters to the function as a single 'parameter'.
It's also advised to have double quotes around such variable `"$*"`.

Some doc on this [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html) section 3.2.5

On the other hand, if you need to iterate through each one of the parameters contained in the argument list, use `$@` instead, like in this ex:

```
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$var"
done
```

Here's another example:
**foo.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash    
foo1()
{
        for x in "$@"
        do
                echo "f1: $x"
        done
}

foo2()
{
        for x in "$*"
        do
                echo "f2: $x"
        done
}

foo1 1 2 "3 4 5" 6 7
echo
foo2 1 2 "3 4 5" 6 7
```

**output**:

```
$  ./foo.sh 
f1: 1
f1: 2
f1: 3 4 5
f1: 6
f1: 7

f2: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: `$*` passes the parameters as a single parameter **only** when you use double quotes: `"$*"`. I believe that's the main use of `$*`, with double quotes. Otherwise, for a list of parameters, `"$@"` is chosen.

Answer (score 2):

`$*` means the all [positional parameters](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams).

Answer (score 2):

`$*` is the list of the positional parameters, but with word splitting. For instance, on

```
your_script ab "cd ef"
```

`$*` will give you 3 arguments: `ab`, `cd` and `ef`. Using `"$@"` is much safer (unless you want word splitting).