# what does "$@" mean inside a find command

Tags: find

I recently saw a script in which below find command was used:

`find "$@" -type f -name "*.iso"`

What does `"$@"` mean here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between $\* and $@?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571/what-is-the-difference-between-and) (going by [what does $* mean in shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141287/what-does-mean-in-shell))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"$@"` expands to all arguments passed to the shell. It has nothing to do with `find` specifically.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

> @
>
> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the
>   expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a
>   separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ... If the
>   double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the
>   first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original
>   word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last
>   part of the original word. When there are no positional parameters,
>   "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

A more succinct practical+relevant example below.

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash -x
find "$@" -ls
$ ./a.sh foo bar blah
+ find foo bar blah -ls
15481123719088698      4 -rw-rw-rw-   1 steve    steve           4 Jun 30 19:29 foo
17451448556173323      0 -rw-rw-rw-   1 steve    steve           0 Jun 30 19:29 bar
find: ‘blah’: No such file or directory
$
```

Comment: Of course it’s more common for the initial argument(s) to `find` to be directories to search, and not files.